# AsyncTask onPostExecute not reached

Tags: android, android-asynctask, tcpclient

I'm trying to execute this `AsyncTask` to connect to the server but it is stuck and doesn't reach `onPostExecute()`.

```
class UnoConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                IP = enterIP.getText().toString();
                Response = "";
                Log.i("Network", "Available");
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
                    Log.i("Socket", "Trying to create...");
                    socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, 4444), 2000);
                    Log.i("Socket", "Created: " + socket.toString());
                    return true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                Log.i("Socket", "Post..." + aBoolean);
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                if (aBoolean) {
                    connect.setChecked(true);
                    showToast("Connected :)", "long");
                    enable(controls);
                    enterIP.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    showToast("Unable to connect...!", "long");
                    connect.setChecked(false);
                    disable(controls);
                    enterIP.setEnabled(true);
                }

                Log.i("Socket", "Post..." + aBoolean);
            }

        }
```

The Method calling this AsyncTask is below:

```
switch (thisView.getId()) {
        case R.id.connect:
            UnoCon = new UnoConnection();
            UnoCon.execute();
            while (!(UnoCon.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                Log.i("UnoCon",UnoCon.getStatus().toString());
            }
            if (socket == null) break;
            cmdSend = new commandSender();
            cmdSend.execute('2', 'R');
            while (!(cmdSend.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                Log.i("cmdSend", "Not Finished Yet");
            }
            if (commandSent) {
                respRec = new responseReceiver();
                respRec.execute();
                while (!(respRec.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                    Log.i("respRec", "Not Finished Yet");
                }
                switch (Response) {
                    case "1":
                        Relay1.setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case "0":
                        Relay1.setChecked(false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            Log.i("Socket", socket.getInetAddress().toString());
            break;
```

So when enabling the above `//Log.i("UnoCon",UnoCon.getStatus().toString());` it always give running.

When I tried using some breakpoints I realized that it:

- Enters `doInBackground` & does everything with no exception
- return true then move to return false without even writing the stacktrace
- jumps to `AsyncTask` class & then I don't know what happens

Comment: why you use while statement

Comment: **return true then move to return false without even writing the stacktrace**. This is not possible

Comment: @karimkhan
I added the while to make sure I execute the rest of my code only after the task is finished and I'm connected

Comment: @user370305
removing super.onPostExecute didn't help

Comment: when I removed the while loop, the Log.i("Socket", "Post..." + aBoolean) was executed...but I need that loop or something that replaces it

Comment: no @user370305 I still not able to see it is super is removed

Comment: So what are you want to execute in while loop? Is there any specific code which you can move to `onPostExecute()` itself.

Comment: not at all, I only use it to wait until the task is finished so that I can step forward

Comment: Wrong. Do not do that like that. Put the code you want to execute after the task has finished in a function. Then call that function in onPostExecute().

Comment: I edited the code above to show you my full code.
After this task is done, I want to do another and then another
and this scenario may differ so I can't keep them in the onPostExecute of the 1st task

Comment: Never block Main UI Thread for running asynctask. I would suggest you to use AsyncTaskExecutor to run all task and display progress dialog to make UI responsive.

Comment: @user370305
the tasks only take about 200ms they are very fast and light so the UI will not be blocked for a long time
anyway...how may I use that Executor here?

Comment: An executor will not help you if the next async tasks depends on the former one. Put all your code after the first asynctask call in a function. Of course you should remove those while()s. Then call that function in every onPostExecute. That function should have a parameter that tells what kind of task has to be launched next.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you called cancel() on your AsyncTask

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line:

```
 while (!(UnoCon.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
     Log.i("UnoCon",UnoCon.getStatus().toString());
 }
```

you start the stuff on the bakcgorund thread, but then you block the UI thread.

First that is completely wrong. Blocking the UI thread with a `while loop` waiting for something from the background thread is just as bad as doing the background work directly on the UI thread.

Then the reason `onPostExecute` doesn't execute is because this method is on the queue to be processed on the UI thread, but you're blocking the UI thread.

To fix it you have to remove this loop and find another way of processing whatever you're processing after the background thread finishes.